# Is there a derivation for the Posterior Predictive Distribution?

Tags: probability, bayesian, predictive-models, posterior

I came across this term in the deep learning book:

$p(x_{m+1}|x_1 ... x_m) = \int p(x_{m+1}|\theta)p(\theta|x_1 ... x_m)d\theta$

After some research I find that this term is the [definition](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_mcmc_sect034.htm) of the posterior predictive distribution. Is there a mathematical or intuitive proof of this? I'd prefer mathematical but anything helps right now.

EDIT: By proof, I am asking how LHS is equal to the RHS. For example, does this also work? If so, how do I arrive at PPD from the Bayes theorem?

$\frac{p(x_{m+1},x_1 ... x_m)}{p(x_1 ... x_m)} = \int p(x_{m+1}|\theta)p(\theta|x_1 ... x_m)d\theta$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't arrive directly from Bayes Theorem because the model has further assumptions. That is, given the parameter set $\theta$, $x_{m+1}$ is independent of previous data; However, if not given we can infer from previous samples which is what PPD is trying to do actually. Without any assumptions, the integral should have been the following:
$$p(x_{m+1}|x_1,...,x_m)=\int p(x_{m+1}|\theta,x_1,...,x_m)p(\theta|x_1,...,x_m)d\theta$$
But, we summarize $p(x_{m+1}|\theta,x_1,...,x_m)$ as $p(x_{m+1}|\theta)$ assuming conditional independence. Your link has also the following sentence:

> Given the assumption that the observed and unobserved data are
>   conditional independent given $\theta$.

Comment: Thanks for the catch! I didn't notice that statement in the link.

Comment: Followup question though: So, $x_{m+1}$ is *not* indenpendent of $x_1 ... x_m$; it's independent of $x_1 ... x_m$ *given* $\theta$. Is this correct? Because the former means that the LHS is just $p(x_{m+1})$.

Comment: Yes, that's the whole idea. There is conditional independence, not full independence.